# How to call action from action on Axios response Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to implement the following logic: call login then if response is ok, call method for retrieving user data.

Login action

```
loginUser({commit,dispatch}, credentials) {
            const form = new URLSearchParams();
            form.append("login", credentials.login);
            form.append("password", credentials.password);

            const formConfig = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            };

         return  Axios.post(loginUrl, form, formConfig).then(
                (response) => {
                    commit('setErrorMessage', '', {root: true});
                    commit('setAuthenticated', response.headers[authorization]);
                    dispatch('getUserByLoginAuth',credentials.login);
                },
                (error) => {
                    if (error.response.status===500){
                        commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data.message, {root: true});
                    } else {
                        commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data, {root: true});
                    }

                });

        },
```

The second action dispatched from the one above:

```
getUserByLoginAuth({commit, getters}, login) {
            return getters.authenticatedAxios.get(userUrl + '/find', {
                params: {
                    login: login
                }
            }).then(
                (response) => {
                    commit('setErrorMessage', '', {root: true});
                    commit('setUser', response.data);
                },
                (error) => {
                    commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data, {root: true});
                });
        },
```

This action is called from the second time only(as I understand it is related to promise).

Here is a code from component which dispatches login action

```
this.$store.dispatch('loginUser', this.credentials).then(() => {
                    this.errorMessage = this.getError;
                    if (this.errorMessage.length) {
                        this.errorOccurred = true;

                    }
                    this.$router.push({path: '/user/' + this.getId});
                });
                this.errorOccurred = false;
            },
```

Here also I am not sure if I am doing routing in correct place. As I understand then will work with promise from getUser so errorMessage from login might be lost. I would like to prevent it and make dispatch of getUser correctly from the first time

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely follow what you're asking but this seems likely to be a problem:

```js
dispatch('getUserByLoginAuth',credentials.login);
```

The problem isn't the call itself. The problem is that it's kicking off a new asynchronous action without chaining it onto the existing promises. From the perspective of `loginUser` everything is done, it won't wait for `getUserByLoginAuth`.

The result will be that the `then` in your component will be called before `getUserByLoginAuth` is done. I would imagine this is why it seems to work the second time, because it's picking up the relevant data from the previous call.

The solution would be simply to change it to:

```js
return dispatch('getUserByLoginAuth',credentials.login);
```

By putting in a `return` it adds it to the promise chain, so `loginUser` won't be treated as complete until `getUserByLoginAuth` is done.

Comment: the only question: should I do like this

         return  Axios.post(loginUrl, form, formConfig).then(
                (response) => {
                   
                   return  dispatch('getUserByLoginAuth',credentials.login);
                },

Comment: @AlexBondar The change I was proposing was simply to put the word `return` at the start of that line. Everything else should stay as it was in the question. The code you just posted seems to have removed two calls to `commit`. There's no need to remove those.

Comment: it this way doesn't work as dispatch is not called in return

Comment: @AlexBondar I don't know what `dispatch is not called in return` means.

Comment: this line return dispatch('getUserByLoginAuth',credentials.login) doesn'r work

Comment: @AlexBondar I can't figure out what the problem is when the only thing you've told me is that it `doesn't work`. Earlier you implied that `dispatch` was not called but that would only happen if you put the `return` on a different line from the `dispatch`. I suggest you use console logging to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: @skritle console in browser shows nothing, but server logs show that only one call is made(for login)